# Why is filereader not working?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io, filereader

I have a chat app built with socket.io and node.js. I have a function below for reading the file from the input and sending it to the server as a base64 string.

```
function readURL() {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
         var FR= new FileReader();
         FR.onload = function(e) {
              $("img").attr("src", e.target.result);
              socket.emit('image', e.target.result);
              console.log(e.target.result);
         };       
         FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
    } 
};
```

My HTML is as follows:

```
<input id="file" type='file' onchange="readURL()"/>
<img id="img">
```

However, upon uploading a file, nothing happens. No errors are recorded, and nothing is even logged to the console. Why is this so?

Comment: How do you listen to your socket in NodeJS?

Comment: It may happen because there is no `this.files` inside the function's scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code you showed is all there is, then this will fix it

You need to pass a reference from the input's `onchange` method, here done using `this` and then add a parameter to the function, here done using `el`

*Note, as `this` is a valid javascript operator, no error will be generated in your original code snippet.*

*You can read more about `this` here: [JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)*

```js
function readURL(el) {
    if (el.files && el.files[0]) {
         var FR= new FileReader();
         FR.onload = function(e) {
              $("img").attr("src", e.target.result);
              socket.emit('image', e.target.result);
              console.log(e.target.result);
         };       
         FR.readAsDataURL( el.files[0] );
    } 
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="file" type='file' onchange="readURL(this)"/>
<img id="img">
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked well. However, before uploading the file it says that Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined. This prevents the app from running the node.js commands until the image is uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing selected file in wrong object. 
If you have below html

```
<input id="file" type='file' onchange="readURL()"/>
```

then to get the file object in "readURL" method, try this:

```
var file = (((this.file || {}).files || [])[0]);
```

@Hundotte .. hope it will help you.